# Add a custom meta box in the post options that loads some html code in the header

Tags: posts, custom-field, customization

I run a blog that is built in the format -

### Logo - Nav

### Large Image + Email Optin Form

### Content / Sidebar

### Footer

Now I want the large image and email opt in form to be optional.

Right now, what I have done is included it as a seperate php file and set it to show on certain pages using post IDs.

But I wanted to add a custom meta box, so as to allow me writers to select whether it is shown or not.

TLDR - Simply want a Custom Meta Checkbox which includes or doesn't include a php file in the header.php

Any help is appreciated.